# Let $f$ holomorphic funcion in $U$ such that $\left|f\right|$ constant on the border of $K$. Show that $f$ is constant or $f$ have a zero in $K^{0}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Let $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ be an open and connected set and $K\subset U$ a compact subset with nonempty interior $K^{o}$. Let $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic funcion such that $\left|f\right|$ constant on the border of $K$. Show that $f$ is constant or $f$ have a zero in $K^{0}$.

**Remark:**  By the maximum modulus principle for $U$ I know that:

- $\left|f\right|$  have a maximum in $U$, or
- $f$ is constant in $U$.

If the function is  constant, then we're done.

If the function is not constant, then we have to show that $f$ have a zero in $K^{0}$. Indeed,  someone gave me the following hint: *if $f$ has no zero inside $K$, i.e, in $k^{o}$, then consider $\frac{1}{f}$ and use the maximum modulus principle*. But do not know how to apply it to this problem, if the set was a disc would be immediate but the set is not necessarily a disk.

Comment: yes the maximum modulus (which states that the maximum modulus of a function holomorphic on a closed subset $K$ is on the boundary of $K$) is a good idea : $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $K$ so $|f(z)| \le \max_{|z| \in K} |f(z)| = 1$ and if it has no zero on $K$ then $1/f(z)$ is holomorphic too on $K$ so $|1/f(z)| \le \max_{|z| \in K} |1/f(z)| = 1$

Comment: **The maximum modulus principle** of my course say: *Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ open and $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic, then $\left|f\right|$ have not maximum in $U$ or $f$ is constant.*

Comment: which means that if it is also holomorphic on the boundary, the maximum modulus lie there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We suppose that $f$ hasn't zeros in $K$. If $f$ hasn't zeros in $K$ then by minimum modulus principle $|f|$ assumes minimum on $\partial K$ , $\min |f(z)|=k$.
Now we use the maximum modulus principle that claims that $|f|$ take maximum on the boundary,but $f$ is constant on $\partial{K}$, then $\min |f(z)|=k=\max |f(z)|$.
We have shown that $|f|$ is constant on $K$. Now, we note that $f \cdot \bar{f}=|f|^2$ .Then we obtain $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}(|f(z)|^2)=0=\bar{f}\cdot\dfrac{\partial f }{\partial z}$, and we obtain the thesis.